# Python: Create an incrementing variable that changes based on a condition

Tags: python, loops, pandas, group-by

I want to create a variable called 'inc' that increments sequentially each time a condition is met (say, Delta>=5), holds the same otherwise, and resets to 1 each time it encounters a new group (ID in this example).  So here's an example dataframe:

```
from pandas import *
d={'rx': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
    'vals': [1,2,3,8,10,1,10,20,21,22]}
df=DataFrame(d)


def diff_func(df):
    return df.diff()                                

df['delta'] = df.groupby(['rx'])['vals'].apply(diff_func)
```

Which produces this:

```
rx  vals delta
1   1    NaN
1   2    1
1   3    1
1   8    5
1   10   2
2   1    NaN
2   10   9
2   20   10
2   21   1
2   22   1
```

So now I want to create a new column called 'Event' that I will later use to group observations within each value of rx separated by a delta < 5:

```
rx  vals    delta   Event
1   1       NaN     1
1   2       1       1
1   3       1       1
1   8       5       2
1   10      2       2
2   1       NaN     1
2   10      9       2
2   20      10      3
2   21      1       3
2   22      1       3
```

Note that 'event' returns to 1 on the first occurrence of rx.  I am used to doing this in vbasic or SAS, where you simply retain a value and then increment by 1 each time the threshold trigger is met.  Is there a similarly simple solution to this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to do a comparison and then a cumulative sum.  For example, something like:

```
>>> df["Event"] = (df["delta"] >= 5).groupby(df["rx"]).cumsum() + 1
>>> df
   rx  vals  delta  Event
0   1     1    NaN      1
1   1     2      1      1
2   1     3      1      1
3   1     8      5      2
4   1    10      2      2
5   2     1    NaN      1
6   2    10      9      2
7   2    20     10      3
8   2    21      1      3
9   2    22      1      3
```

which works because (ignoring the groupby for simplicity and concentrating only on `rx == 1`:) `False == 0` and `True == 1`:

```
>>> df["delta"]
0   NaN
1     1
2     1
3     5
4     2
Name: delta, dtype: float64
>>> df["delta"] >= 5
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: delta, dtype: bool
>>> (df["delta"] >= 5).cumsum()
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
Name: delta, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Elegant solution--love it!

Answer (score 0):

```
def diff_func(df:pd.DataFrame):
    return df.assign(Event=df.delta.ge(5).cumsum().add(1))

df1.fillna(1).astype(int).groupby(['rx'],as_index=False).apply(diff_func)


┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ index │  rx   │ vals  │ delta │ Event │
│ int64 │ int32 │ int32 │ int32 │ int32 │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│     0 │     1 │     1 │     1 │     1 │
│     1 │     1 │     2 │     1 │     1 │
│     2 │     1 │     3 │     1 │     1 │
│     3 │     1 │     8 │     5 │     2 │
│     4 │     1 │    10 │     2 │     2 │
│     5 │     2 │     1 │     1 │     1 │
│     6 │     2 │    10 │     9 │     2 │
│     7 │     2 │    20 │    10 │     3 │
│     8 │     2 │    21 │     1 │     3 │
│     9 │     2 │    22 │     1 │     3 │
├───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┤
│ 10 rows                     5 columns │
└───────────────────────────────────────┘
```